# Does synchronized(this) imply that the current thread object acquired its own lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following piece of code -

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    private int x = 5;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) // <-- what does it mean?
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread m = new MyThread();
        m.start();

        synchronized (m) {
            try {
                m.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, does Thread m acquire the lock on itself?

Comment: One thing to point out @CodeBlue is that your code has a race condition.  The thread might start, do its `println` and call `notify()` _before_ the `main` gets to the `wait()`.  Probably given the IO this is unlikely but it could happen.  Just FYI.

Comment: @Gray, yes, you are right! This code was just for illustration purposes, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current thread acquires the lock on the associated instance of the `MyThread` class.

The `synchronized(this)` is locking the same object as `synchronized(m)` in `main()`.

Finally,

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
public synchronized void run() {
```

Comment: This. Also, distinguish between a thread of execution and the actual Thread object that spawned and let's you talk to it.

Comment: Why is that good @Prince?  I see no relevance to that to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the equivalence of the two statements you mentioned!!

Comment: @Gray: because synchronizing on non final value is not a good practice and yes it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. The thread acquires a lock on the instance of the class (MyThread).

Answer (score 0):

You have to see it as any other java object. what you have typed means that other threads can't access this java object (independently if it was a thread instance or not because it doesn't make difference.